# How to split String on two different chars

Tags: java, arrays, split

I already splitted the String value2 on the char "-" and saved its values in a new array as you can see. Now I wanna seperate the String again on the "," and save it again in a new array but it doesn't work. It always just seperates the second name with the number. And overrites the first. So I got in the first Array on [0]: Peter,2 and in [1]: Leo,1
and in the second array just on [0] Leo and on [1] 1.

I know my for loop is wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

```
    final int value = 2;
    final String value2 = "Peter,2-Leo,1";


    String[] splittedStringOne = new String[value];
    String[] splittedStringTwo = new String[splittedStringOne.length*2];


    splittedStringOne = value2.split("-");



    for(int i=0;i<splittedStringOne.length;i++) {
        splittedStringTwo=splittedStringOne[i].split(",");
```

Comment: Have your tried with two dimensional array?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I would suggest to replace all "-" to "," first then split by ",". This way you will split only once and get the desired array.

Comment: yes I want to do a two dimensional array after I putted the values in the second array right.

Comment: Sometimes debugging would help to get more insight into the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

splittedStringTwo has to be 2 dimensional.

```
String[][] splittedStringTwo = new String[splitedStringOne.length][2];

for(int i =0; i < splittedStringTwo.length; i++)
    splittedStringTwo[i] = splittedStringOne[i].split(",");
```

Or if you dont want a 2 dimensional array:

```
String[] splittedStringTwo = new String[splittedStringOne.length*2];

for(int i = 0; i < splittedStringTwo.length; i+=2){
    String[] split = splittedStringOne[i].split(",");
    splittedStringTwo[i] = split[0];
    splittedStringTwo[i+1] = split[1];
}
```

**EDIT:**
For question in the comments. Try this out, it is not tested but it should work

```
String[][] splittedStringTwo = new String[splittedStringOne.length*2][2];

for(int i = 0; i < splittedStringTwo.length; i+=2){
    String[] split1 = splittedStringOne[i].split(",");
    String[] split2 = splittedStringOne[i+1].split(",");
    splittedStringTwo[i][0] = split1[0] 
    splittedStringTwo[i][1] = split2[0];
    splittedStringTwo[i+1][0] = split1[1]
    splittedStringTwo[i+1][1] = split2[1];
}
```

Comment: But how can I fill up the splittedStringTwo array that i have then: {{Peter,Leo},{2,1}}

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I want in the second dimension all the names separated and all the numbers separated. The input String is: Peter,2-Leo,1. And then I split twice and in the end I wanna have in the 2D array {{Peter,Leo},{2,1}}. Not {{Peter,2},{Leo,1}}.

Comment: What does Array constants can only be used in initializers mean? This is the error if i wanna do `splittedStringTwo[i] = {split1[0], split2[0]};
    splittedStringTwo[i+1] = {split1[1], split2[1]}`

Comment: Okay the curly brackets are not possible in java in allocations.. now it should work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your splittedStringOne contains the right values at index [0] and [1], in your for loop, you will just overwrite the content of splittedStringTwo. 
Since String.split(',') returns an array, you should also make splittedStringTwo two dimensional :

```
    String[][] splittedStringTwo = new String[splitedStringOne.length][2];
```

This should work for the for loop:

```
    for(int i=0;i<splittedStringOne.length;i++) {
    splittedStringTwo[i]  = splittedStringOne[i].split(",");
    }
```

note that I added [i] to splittedStringTwo

Answer (score -1):

You can use arraycopy to copy the result of `splittedStringOne[i].split(",");` to the correct position of splittedStringTwo

like:

```
public class ArrayCopyTest {

    @Test public void test() {
        final String value2 = "Peter,2-Leo,1";

        String[] splittedStringOne = value2.split("-");
        String[] splittedStringTwo = new String[splittedStringOne.length*2];

        for(int i=0;i<splittedStringOne.length;i++) {
            // splittedStringTwo = splittedStringOne[i].split(",");
            System.arraycopy(splittedStringOne[i].split(","), 0, splittedStringTwo, i * 2, 2);
        }
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(splittedStringTwo, new String[]{"Peter", "2", "Leo", "1"});
    }

}
```